# HttpClient issue in angular5

Tags: angular5

I am working with Angular 4 with HttpService, i am trying to migrate to HttpClientService.

but i am getting the error as below

```
ERROR in src/app/app.service.ts(19,102): error TS2559: Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
```

please refer my app.service.ts also

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    private token: any = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjYxMmMyMDEyNmI1ZTY1ZGE3NWE3YmQ3MmJlNGYzMDIzYWZ5a9';
    public headers = new Headers({
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : `Bearer ${this.token}`
    });
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData() {
        return this.http.get('http://192.111.99.**/cloudnew/public/api/generic/registrations/view/0', this.headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that read `new HttpHeaders({...` instead?

Comment: in node js command prompt it is showing like that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment below.... I would suggest implementing Http interceptors.... something like this....

You first need an authentication service that grabs the token at first, then you can store the token ad send it with each request with interceptors..

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.login().subscribe(res=> this.handleLogin(res)));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s=> s.unsubscribe());
  }

  getBaseHeader(): HttpHeaders {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return header;
  }

  getAuthHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.token
    });
    return headers;
  }

  getHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    if(this.token && this.validateToken()) {
      return this.getAuthHeaders();
    } else {
      return this.getBaseHeader();
    }
  } 

  storeLogin(response: Response) {
    .... store login token etc...
  }

  getStoredLogin(): any {
    ... get login/token etc...
  }

  getToken(): string {
    return this.token;
  }

  login(): Observable<Response> {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(path, { body to be sent ie login password }, options);
  }

  loggedIn(): boolean {
    return ....login crentials | false/null;
  }

  validateToken() {
    return moment(this.tokenExpiration).isAfter(moment().second());
  }

  handleError(err: Response, fn?: string) {
    console.log(typeof err);
    if(fn) console.log(fn);
    console.log(err.toString());
  }
}
```

then the interceptor......

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authService = this.inj.get(AuthService);
    const authHeader = authService.getHeaders();
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: authHeader});
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

This way you the interceptors do all the work for you after the initil login. Simplified the code to more of a shell than a snippet of a working application

Comment: Is that better? @evilSnobu